# How to determine if a component comprises a React heirarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a popup library that uses React Portal to render every popup to `body` to mitigate `overflow: hidden` issue. Now popups can open up further popups and I want to determine if click is made outside any of these popup hierarchy in order to close all of them. If they were nested, I could do a `.contains` for `e.target`, but here, the DOM hierarchy will be flat (i.e., all popups will be siblings inside body). Only React hierarchy will be nested due to the nature of React Portals. My question is how do I best detect whether a click was made inside this popup hierarchy or outside?

Comment: I'm not sure how your popups are implemented, but maybe you could use `event.stopPropagation()` on the popup click event to make sure only the topmost popup is handled?

Comment: could you please elaborate? each popup consists of a trigger component that listens for clicks and a popup component that renders on click. Where do I place the click handler and how do I detect topmost popup?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code, but your Modal most likely has a `onClick` handler of sorts, so if you write `<Modal onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} />` it might just work as you would like, since only the Modal that got clicked will get the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using react context to send popup's closing function down to its children. The children, if they are popup themselves, can call it's own closing function and then delegating further propagation by calling parent closing function.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with detecting clicks outside of react subtree.
All You need is set handler on DOM element, rendered up the portal. And another handler should be added to the document. So You can "mark" event with handler, before it bubbles to the document.

Wrote package for such cases:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-on-outside-event